# Efficient way to parse using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, parsing, optimization

I am working on a program supposed to parse several files at the same time. My question is :

What is the fastest way to do it using threads?

For example, considering I have 6 threads, and n files to parse, would it be faster to :

-Cut the n file into six part, and give one part to each thread and then go to next file

-Cut the n file into two parts and give it to two threads so I can parse 3 files at the same time

-Give one file to each thread.

If don't know if it does matter, but I have to use c++, `pthread` for my threads.

Do not hesitate to ask me if you need more details of if you don't understand something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well,  giving each thread it's own file solves most synchronization problems.

Comment: But would it be faster?

Comment: I would be surprised if the complexity of parsing a document in pieces, that need to be stitched together in a synchronized manner, would be more efficient that parsing it whole, given sufficient memory. But that's just a gut feeling, I guess you could do some tests.

Comment: Not sure.  Really you would need to build it and test it to know for sure.  Personally I shoot for the easier way first and then improve only when I know it is a problem.

Comment: Ok, I see, I will probably do that, thanks!

Comment: How big are the files, or how long does it take to parse a single file?

Comment: Can we assume the `n` files are all completely independent of each other?

Comment: @xander, It can be any file, but it has to work in as many situations as possible. I don't know yet, I've asked this question before computing, to know how I should do it.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, totally!

Comment: @souki depends on how often you went to parse multiple files at the same time. If it would be almost always, the I've thread or file is definitely simpler. If half of the time you parse only once file, the threaded file parsing becomes tempting, but is much more difficult to implement, and if not done properly, can be actually slower.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot the thing is that I do not decide, the program will basicaly wait for a command line telling which files to parse. It depends on what the user wants. You think I should go for a file for each thread?

Comment: @NathanOliver will this not cause the program to become IO bound and therefore potentially slower or the same speed as just iterating files and parsing them on a single thread?